# How can I run django application using Aptana Studio

Tags: django, aptana

Can anyone please help setting and running django project using Aptana Studio?

Comment: Can you give some more details on what help do you need? I mean have you tried to use it yet? HAve you experience with working with Eclipse?

Comment: Currently I am using Aptana Studio as project explorer tool, wherein, I can see my files folder. It gives me intellisense to some extent. 
I wish Aptana should also have run and debug facility for django application. 
I have not tried eclipse yet... But Aptana itself uses pydev plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Hello World" tutorial right [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131220223418/http://blog.yawd.eu/2011/using-aptana-studio-3-ide-django-applications-simp/) (Note: The original site is no longer up, so this now points to a web archive version)

Comment: Link now gives a 502 Bad Gateway :(

Comment: Here's the [web archive for it](http://web.archive.org/web/20131220223418/http://blog.yawd.eu/2011/using-aptana-studio-3-ide-django-applications-simp/).